# Is it possible to enable autocompletion of SASS / Less mixins and variables from connected files in the VS Code?

Tags: sass, visual-studio-code, less

Please help me understand if VS Code can enable autocompletion of the names of mixins and variables from Less and SASS files connected via `@import`?

Something doesn’t work out for me.
The VS Code documentation says that the syntax of the preprocessors seems to support, but actually does not work (the files are correctly connected correctly)

P.S. Maybe there is some kind of extension?

[Sass](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Syler.sass-indented) and [Less IntelliSense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrmlnc.vscode-less) apps didn't help

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: [VS Code docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/css): "VS Code has support for *selectors, properties and values*.". That's it for now.

Comment: @seven-phases-max, Very sorry. Thanks for the answer. It is strange that there are still no extensions for this.